# Overloading a C++ type to handle a custom class

Tags: c++, class, overloading

Currently just messing around with overloading types and returning different things, but this one error has stumped me and I do not know how to google it.

The idea is, I have a "2dvector" class and I want to return the dot product to a single value and not vector form. 
Example: 
    float dproduct = vec_a * vec_b;

I have successfully overloaded "*" to be dot product for my class. Though I'm stumped on how to take two classes, take the dot product as a single value, and return it into a different type.

My current thinking is this:

```
const float operator= (vec2& right);

const float vec2::operator= (vec2& right){
return (right.x + right.y);
}
```

Since the right side should evaluate properly since vec_a * vec_b will return a "vec_c" result.

Comment: Isn't the dot product a scalar number? Didn't you mean that you already implemented the '*' operation on two vectors as the cross product, which returns a vector.

Comment: You cannot overload **types**. You can overload **functions**, based on the types of the arguments that they take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `vec_a * vec_b` portion, you need an `operator*()` to compute the product of two `vec2` objects and return a new `vec2`, eg:

```
vec2 operator* (const vec2 &left, const vec2 &right)
{
    vec2 tmp;
    // fill with the product of left and right...
    return tmp;
}
```

For the `float dproduct = ...` portion, you need a conversion operator to convert a single `vec2` into a number:

```
class vec2
{
public:
    operator float () const;
};

vec2::operator float () const
{
    return (this.x + this.y);
}
```

IOW, this statement:

```
float dproduct = vec_a * vec_b;
```

Equates to this series of calls:

```
float dproduct = ::operator*(vec_a, vec_b).operator float();
```

Comment: The second part is exactly what I needed. just the conversion. Thank you so much!